# Word wrap at only "Space" After break word into <span> class for each charactor

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap

My Javascript text animation needs to break word into `<span>` class for each character, and after this word wrap is not working properly. Because words are breaking anywhere, I want them to only break at a "space". How can I do this from JS & CSS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldPw6.png)

Here is complete code of my JS CSS & HTML

```
<h1 class="rks1">A rose is a woody perennial flowering plant of the genus Rosa, in the family Rosaceae, or the flower it bears. There are over three hundred species and thousands of cultivars. They form a group of plants  </h1>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>

<style>
.rks1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: rr;
}

.rks1 .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
</style>

<script>

// Wrap every letter in a span
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.rks1');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.rks1 .letter',
    scale: [3.5,1],
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateZ: 0,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 450,
    delay: (el, i) => 50*i
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml2',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 500
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each "word" you find, wrap each word in a span as well and style that such that it does not wrap. E.g.

```
.word {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

---

Example:

```js
// Wrap every letter in a span
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.rks1');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, function(m) {
  return `<span class="word">`
    + m.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>")
    + `</span>`;
});

anime.timeline({loop: false})
  .add({
    targets: '.rks1 .letter',
    scale: [3.5,1],
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateZ: 0,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 450,
    delay: (el, i) => 50*i
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml2',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 500
  });
```

```css
.rks1 {
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 2.5em;
font-family: rr;
}

.rks1 .letter {
display: inline-block;
line-height: 1em;
}

.word {
background-color: #CFF;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="rks1">A rose is a woody perennial flowering plant of the genus Rosa, in the family Rosaceae, or the flower it bears. There are over three hundred species and thousands of cultivars. They form a group of plants  </h1>
```

Comment: Hello Chase can you make my one more help plz, it will be gracefull for me.

Comment: Please Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62114063/wrap-every-letter-in-a-span-by-js-but-except-some-character-they-must-be-add